# При наведении на ссылки не срабатывают стили hover

Tags: html, css, scss, hover

При наведении на ссылку или кнопку не срабатывают стили, заданные для :hover. В гугловских инструментах либо показывает, что они перечёркнуты, либо - что они в норме (но они всё равно не работают!)

P.S. Странно, но если вырвать это из файлов с кодом, то :hover будет работать (только что здесь и в codepen проверил). В чём может быть проблема?

```css
* {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.menubar__button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 305px;
  height: 46px;
  top: 29px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Gilroy;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.menubar__button .menubar__quest {
  margin-right: 13px;
}

.menubar__button .menubar__quest a {
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
  padding: 14px 25px 14px 25px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(5.52deg, #61ADE6 0%, #8FCBF6 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(5.52deg, #61ADE6 0%, #8FCBF6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(84.48deg, #61ADE6 0%, #8FCBF6 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px rgba(97, 173, 229, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px rgba(97, 173, 229, 0.3);
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menubar__button .menubar__enter a {
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
  -o-transition: .3s ease;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 14px 25px 14px 25px;
}

.menubar__quest a:hover {
  background: #61ADE5;
}

.menubar__enter a:hover {
  border-color: #B8BCC3;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menubar__button">
  <li class="menubar__quest"><a href="#">Разместить задание</a></li>
  <li class="menubar__enter"><a href="#">Войти</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.menubar__button .menubar__quest a:hover` а пробовали так? (повысить приоритет стиля)

Comment: Ну если здесь работает, то, очевидно, проблема в конфликтах с другими стилями